# Can we add "Sharepoint List Adapter" SSIS component to visual studio 2013(SSIS)? If yes, then how?

Tags: ssis

I am working on SSIS2013(visual Studio). I need to pull data from sharepoint list, for that I want to add "Sharepoint list adapter" component to toolbox. How can I do that? If not, then what is the solution to read data from sharepoint list using visual studio 2013(SSIS)?